# Count the number of occurences in a file in the last 7 days

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

**Input:**

```
cat log.txt

2021-01-15 00:00:14: Installing hotfix ...
2021-01-15 00:02:07: Hotfix successfully installed!
2021-01-15 00:02:07: Finished
2021-02-07 00:00:14: Installing hotfix ...
2021-02-07 00:02:07: Hotfix successfully installed!
2021-02-07 00:02:07: Finished
2021-02-08 12:00:14: Started - Looking for available hotfixes ...
2021-02-08 12:00:14: Updating the hotfix list
2021-02-08 12:00:14: Finished
```

I would like to create a daily cronjob that updates a `file.txt` with the number of occurrences for the word `installed`, but only for the last 7 days. So, whenever I read `file.txt` it should contain the number of hotfixes installed in the last 7 days.

current date: `2021-02-08`

**Output:**

```
cat file.txt
1
```

I know I can use `grep -c "installed" log.txt` in order to count all the occurrences in the log file. But how can I modify it so that grep only counts the occurrences from the last 7 days? The dates will always change, as new lines are added daily, so I cannot provide fixed dates in the grep script. Also, there might be multiple `installed` occurrences in a given day, so I cannot grep by line number.

Comment: Could you please post more clear samples of input and expected output for better understanding of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v d="$(date -d "7 days ago" "+%F")" '$1 > d && /installed/{c++}END{print c}' log.txt >file.txt
```

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty bad with awk. If ```file.txt``` is the output file, how do I specify the input file ```log.txt```? Do I need to ```cat``` it before awk?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `date` from GNU coreutils and plain `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

linecount=0
weekago=$(date -d "-7 days" +%F)
while read -r line; do
        [[ $line > $weekago ]] && [[ $line = *installed* ]] && ((++linecount))
done < log.txt
echo $linecount > file.txt
```